# Adding addTarget: method to custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, custom-view, uicontrolevents

I created a custom UIView something like UIStepper, because I don't like the appearance of the UIStepper. I want UIStepper have a personal count label so I added it to my custom view and created a method to increase-decrease it. Now I need a **[customView addTarget:(id) action:(del) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)]** method to catch *UIControlEventValueChanged*; but I couldn't find anything about implementing it. I dig around the UIButton.h, UIStepper.h files but no luck too.. Can anyone help me to do that?

Here is how I created the custom view...

**CounterView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CounterView : UIView
@property NSString* name;
@property NSInteger count;
@property UILabel *label;
@property NSInteger customTag;

- (id)initWithX:(CGFloat)xPoint WithY:(CGFloat)yPoint WithName:(NSString*)newName withCount:(NSInteger)newCount withCustomTag:(NSInteger)newTag;
@end
```

**CounterView.m**

```
@implementation CounterView

- (id)initWithX:(CGFloat)xPoint WithY:(CGFloat)yPoint WithName:(NSString*)newName withCount:(NSInteger)newCount withCustomTag:(NSInteger)newTag
{
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPoint, yPoint, 24, 52)];
if (self) {
    self.customTag = newTag;
    self.count = newCount;
    self.name = newName;

    UIButton *btnUp = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 2, 18, 12)];
    [btnUp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnUp addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIButton *btnDown = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 38, 18, 12)];
    [btnDown setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDown addTarget:self action:@selector(decreaseValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 14, 24, 24)];
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)self.count]];
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [self addSubview:btnUp];
    [self addSubview:btnDown];
    [self addSubview:self.label];
}
return self;
}

-(void) increaseValue{
self.count++;
[self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)self.count]];
}
-(void) decreaseValue{
self.count--;
[self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)self.count]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just allow the actions to be set from outside of your control. Here is how to do it:

```
@interface CounterView : UIView
...
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnUp;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnDown;

- (void)addUpTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
- (void)addDownTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end

@implementation CounterView

...

- (void)addUpTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    [_btnUp addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)addDownTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    [_btnDonw addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

...

@end
```

Then use methods:

```
- (void)addUpTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
- (void)addDonwTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
```

to set a target and actions for increasing and decreasing the values.

Comment: But I have 2 UIButtons as subviews. I gave them **UIControlEventTouchUpInside** to update the UILabel's text. I have to re-implement the button clicks with gestureRecognisers in your way?

Comment: OK.. I will give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: No problem.. maybe because of my english =).. Thank you for the help, I will try it. But a way to add **addTarget** method would be better. But may be there is no way to do that.. I don't know yet =)

Answer (score 2):

in the ViewController where you instantiate your CounterView you add this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[yourViewInstantiation addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[singleFingerTap release];
```

and the you implement the call back method:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

  //Do stuff here...
}
```

i hope that help you !

Comment: You say that, don't remove the UIButtons' click, but add a gesture recogniser on them too.. So with button click (UIControlEventTouchUpInside), view will update it's label. And with the gesture recogniser, view will say "I HAVE BEEN CLICKED" to the view controller.. Am I right?

Comment: exactly,
but i see that you have two buttons !!

Comment: the best way is that you implement a NSNotification

Comment: NSNotification... hmm.. I never used it, yet.. Will give it a try too. Thanks.